# How to put an object in a specefic row or column while using pack in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have been making some gui applications using python tkinter.In tkinter pack and grid cannot be used together.While writing a code I had to use pack and then I needed to use 2 features called 'Cloumn' and 'row' of grid but that is impossible.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
button = Button(root, text="Click Me")
button.pack(side="bottom") #But I want to put that button in row=3
root.mainloop()
```

I need to put that button in row number 3.But how can I do it?
Is there any way to do so?

Comment: `pack()` does not work with rows and columns like `grid()` does. In order for you to do rows and columns you need to use `grid()`

Comment: You can use both if you use them in different frames.

Comment: @progmatico well not so much different frames as different containers. There are more containers then just frames.

Comment: @Mike-SMT besides Toplevel or Tk windows?

Comment: @progmatico well there is also PanedWindow, canvas and LabelFrame. That said Tk and Toplevel are also containers so that is at least 6 if you include normal frames. That is why it is important to specify that you can use both in different containers and not just different frames.

Comment: Oh, sure thanks, for moments I forgot those and was actually thinking if every widget could be used as a parent :) ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for pack and grid to be used in the same code you need to make sure you use them on separate containers. Each container (root window, toplevel window, frame) can only have either `grid()` or `pack()`.

For example if I need to use pack on a frame and then use grid inside of that frame that is ok. But I cannot use pack inside the frame and also grid inside the frame.

If you expand the window made from the below code you will see how pack and grid can work together if used properly.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

top_frame = tk.Frame(root)
top_frame.pack(sid="top")
bot_frame = tk.Frame(root)
bot_frame.pack(sid="bottom")

tk.Label(top_frame, text="Row 0 of top_frame").grid(row=0, column=0)

tk.Label(bot_frame, text="Row 0 of bot_frame").grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Label(bot_frame, text="Row 1 of bot_frame").grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Label(bot_frame, text="Row 2 of bot_frame").grid(row=2, column=0)
tk.Button(bot_frame, text="Row 3 of bot_frame").grid(row=3, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```